# Sum values in range if values match in the same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to sum the values in a certain range if values match on column A

[image]

I want to sum the values that are in columns B, C and D and present them on column E

Example:

01/07/2020 is showing on A2, A3 and A4, so I want to sum the values in the range B2:D4 and present the result on E2 (92+32+16=140).

Could you guys help me with this problem?

Comment: Sound like you are looking for [`SUMIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

=SUM(IF($B$3:$B$14=B12;$C$3:$E$14;0))

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already found the answer, I'd like to propose you another one:

You can create a helper column, containing the sum of the first three columns, and then add the "subtotals" Excel feature.

The result, for the mentioned data, will look as follows (sorry for the Dutch):

[image]

Remark: the `Subtotal()` functions are added automatically by the mentioned feature.